# installing sql server management studio 2014

Tags: installation, ssms, sql-server-2014, system-requirements

I am  having trouble installing SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2014 on my  windows 7 machine.
When I try to run setup  it comes  of with following message:

**The operating system on this computer does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL Server 2014**

I have  Windows 7 corporate edition  Service pack1 And  DotNet 4 and  admin access.

I also have it on another machine  with even lower config  but when I try to  update  or config it it comes up with same  message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't there something about SSMS 14 needing .net 3.5 or am I remembering wrong?

Comment: @allan-s-hansen You are right, You need to enable  3.5 feature in control panel which I did.Still no success